# How can you put Android OpenGL ES client and server on different machines

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

All the intro texts to OpenGL ES repeat that, since it's based on OpenGL, it's designed around a client/server model, though these two things tend to be on the same machine.

Well, I would like to put them on separate machines (on the same local network).  Is this possible in Android?  How can it be done?  Extra kudos if you can figure out how to work this into a libgdx scenario (which is the gaming library I use).

(Long-winded and Perhaps Unnecessary Further Information: my use case is in faster prototyping of android games for phones.  It's pretty straight forward to get finger taps and accelerometer data and what not and send it over the network to a PC.  If I can have the PC send gl calls to the phone, then I can effectively run the entire game from the PC, but appear to be running on the phone.  This lets me test and see if a game/game-idea will work on the phone/phone-gpu, from the advantage of far superior ram/cpu/compile-times/hot-swap-code, and just see what works on a phone, before worrying about getting everything into the ram and cpu footprint and logistics of a handset device.  I know I can do this by deconstructing rendered frames, sending byte[] arrays to the device, and using libgdx Pixmap or android BitmapFactory to get the image and render it; but if it's simple to stream gl calls instead, I'd rather do that, especially since it's a more realistic test of the phone gpu's rendering ability)

Comment: I notice that Nicol Bolas removed my "opengl" tag, which I suppose is fair; but the follow up question I would ask is, can you use a regular open-gl client on one end (like pyopengl) and an opengl-es server on the other, if you just stick to the subset of calls that opengl-es supports?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between a protocol supporting remote operation and an implementation of a server or client that does the remote operation.  I don't think there are existing Android implementations that support anything like this.  I suspect any of the "remote desktop" apps just forward 2D images, and don't do anything with OpenGL.

That said, there isn't anything particularly preventing you from implementing a new libGDX backend that would "remote" OpenGL calls to a server that runs on the phone and forwards those  operations to the local OpenGL backend.  (I can only say this with confidence as I have not looked at it any detail....)

However, given that one of the bigger bottlenecks in OpenGL performance is (generally) the bandwidth between the client and the GPU (e.g., uploading textures, vertex data, shaders, etc), adding a network is only going to exacerbate that problem and will make it hard to reason about actual performance on a phone.

You're probably better off running on your desktop and using profiling to make sure you only use a "reasonable" amount of CPU and GPU resources.